# Is there any case where you can't use backtracking algorithm method?

Tags: algorithm, search, backtracking

As the title says, I am **really really really curious** about this. 
I've been trying to find the cases where you can't use backtracking to solve them but I can't find them.
Share your knowledge please

Comment: Please make the question more clear and ask about a specific problem you encountered.

Comment: You need to define what a "case" is and what you consider a "backtracking" algorithm to be. Usually you wouldn't because the context of the problem gives you (mostly) sufficient information. In a broad, theoretical question like this, you need to define those terms precisely to reason about them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there are too many possibilities to check, backtracking search will be impractical - see e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lighthill_report. There may also be cases where you cannot state the problem simply and clearly enough to recognize the correct answer when you find it.